# Using Spring AMQP, my receiver always misses the first message after it is started

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE with spring-boot-starter-amqp v 1.3.0. The Rabbit broker is version RabbitMQ 3.5.6, Erlang 18.1.

I have written a small AMQP message listener application that just accepts messages and writes them to a database. Its based heavily on the [Messaging with Rabbit MQ Spring Guide.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/)

My changes are converting the TopicExchange to a FanoutExchange and adding a call to setConcurrentConsumers(). And I added JDBC, and I also removed the code that sends a message.

It works well except for one issue; each time I start it, it always misses the first message. The sending app is not restarted, and very reliably, when I cause the sending app to send a message, this app misses the first one I send. After that it seems to get them all.

Code is pasted below, thanks for your help.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner 
{
    @Autowired
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurationService cs;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() 
    {
        return new Queue(cs.getRabbitQueue(), false, false, true);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, FanoutExchange exchange) 
    {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange);
    }


    // Added by JWA
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory()
    {
        CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory(cs.getRabbitHost());

        cf.setUsername(cs.getRabbitUserName());
        cf.setPassword(cs.getRabbitPassword());
        cf.setVirtualHost(cs.getRabbitVirtualHost());

        return cf;
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange fanout()
    {
        return new FanoutExchange("logs", false, false);
    }


    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) 
    {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(cs.getRabbitQueue());
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(cs.getRabbitNumListeners());
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);

        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    Receiver receiver() 
    {
        return new Receiver();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) 
    {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception 
    {
            // Nothing to do here
    }

}


public class Receiver 
{
    @Autowired 
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private final static String sql = "INSERT INTO msc_reporting_log (eventtime, rectype, userid, prospect_key, userip, userhostname, phase, decision, reason, loghost, sourcehost) values (?, ?, ?, HEXTORAW(?), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private String hn;

    public void receiveMessage(String message) 
    {
        System.out.println("Received: " + message);

        LogMessage lm = extractJson(message);

        logWithLogger(lm);
        logToDatabase(lm);
    }

    private void logWithLogger(LogMessage lm)
    {
        String msg = "MESSAGE_RECEIVED," + lm;
        Logger.getGlobal().info(msg);
    }

    private void logToDatabase(LogMessage m)
    {
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, m.getEventTime(), m.getType(), m.getUserId(), m.getUserProspectKey(), m.getUserIP(), m.getUserHostName(), m.getPhase(), m.getDecision(), m.getReason(), hn, m.getSourceHostName());
    }

    private LogMessage extractJson(String m)
    {
        try
        {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            LogMessage lm = mapper.readValue(m,  LogMessage.class);
            return lm;
        }
        catch(JsonMappingException jme)
        {
            Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, "Error mapping JSON", jme);
            jme.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(JsonParseException jpe)
        {
            Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, "Error parsing JSON", jpe);
            jpe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, "IO Error while extracting JSON", ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

As far as the timing of this error, the publisher program is running before I start this listener. I start the listener. I then cause the publisher to send a message, usually by making an incorrect login. The publisher produces the message, and the receiver app seems to not notice at all. I do it again, and the second message is then received.

I have modified the receiver application to use an anonymous queue instead, because i want to run multiple instances of this logger application for redundancy. The issue still happens. Here is the new receiver code, the publisher code and the receiver pom:

Receiver POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.xxxxx.ua</groupId>
    <artifactId>DecisionsLogger</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

New app, has the same problem as the one above:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner 
{
    @Autowired
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurationService cs;

    public String getLocalHostname()
    {
        return cs.getLocalHostName();
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() 
    {
        //return new Queue(cs.getRabbitQueue(), false, false, true);
        return new AnonymousQueue();
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(FanoutExchange exchange) 
    {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory()
    {
        CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory(cs.getRabbitHost());

        cf.setUsername(cs.getRabbitUserName());
        cf.setPassword(cs.getRabbitPassword());
        cf.setVirtualHost(cs.getRabbitVirtualHost());

        return cf;
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange fanout()
    {
        return new FanoutExchange(cs.getRabbitExchange(), false, false);
    }


    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) 
    {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(cs.getRabbitMinListeners());
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(cs.getRabbitMaxListeners());
        return factory;
    }   


    @Bean
    Receiver receiver() 
    {
        return new Receiver();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) 
    {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception 
    {
        while(true) {}
            // Nothing to do here
    }

}
```

Publisher code:

```
@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
```

Elsewhere in the same class as the @Autowired above:

```
private void send(Message m)
{
    if(!isActive)
        return;


    if(rabbitTemplate == null)
    {
        DecLogger.DEC.fine(() -> "Unable to send Rabbit Message - rabbitTemplate is null");
        return;
    }

    if(configSvc.getRabbitQueue() == null)
    {
        DecLogger.DEC.fine(() -> "Unable to send Rabbit Message - queueName is null");
        return;
    }


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       

    String time = ZonedDateTime.now().toString();
    m.setEventTime(time);

    try
    {
        String tmpStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(m);

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(configSvc.getRabbitExchange(), configSvc.getRabbitQueue(), tmpStr);

        DecLogger.DEC.finest(() -> "Sent Rabbit Message: " + tmpStr);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        DecLogger.DEC.fine(() -> "Failed sending Rabbit Message");
        DecLogger.DEC.fine(() -> "Exception: " + e);
    }
}
```

The Message class used above is not from Spring Framework (I should rename it):

```
abstract class Message 
{
    @JsonProperty
    private String eventTime;

    @JsonProperty 
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty
    protected String sourceHostName;


    public Message(String type, String sourceHostName)
    {
        setType(type);
        setSourceHostName(sourceHostName);
    }

    public void setEventTime(String time)
    {
        this.eventTime = time;
    }

    private void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    private void setSourceHostName(String sourceHostName)
    {
        this.sourceHostName = sourceHostName;
    }


}
```

**ISSUE RESOLVED**

The problem turned out to be on the producer side. This line:

```
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(configSvc.getRabbitExchange(), configSvc.getRabbitQueue(), tmpStr);
```

was replaced with this line:

```
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(configSvc.getRabbitExchange(), "", tmpStr);
```

The only change being the second parameter. Apparently providing the routing key in the second parameter of convertAndSend() caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>What you are seeing makes no sense to me; my first step would be to turn on DEBUG logging and watch the message flow - so you can see if the message arrives at the container at all. If not, you need to look elsewhere.</strike>

Another thing to look for is a message sitting in unacked state in the management console. That would imply there's another consumer someplace; you can see the consumers on the management console.

**Aside:** Why are you mixing boot jar versions? I am not suggesting that's the issue, but I'd use the 1.2.7 starter with boot 1.2.7 or switch everything to 1.3.0.

I see the problem:

```
return new Queue(cs.getRabbitQueue(), false, false, true);
```

This creates an `auto-delete` queue.

So when your app is not running, the queue disappears and publishing to the `fanout` does nothing.

The `RabbitAdmin` provided by Boot will re-create the queue when the app starts.

Try:

```
return new Queue(cs.getRabbitQueue());
```

tben the queue will remain after the app stops.

Comment: I edited the answer - the queue is being deleted when your app stops.

Comment: Hi Gary and thanks very much for the response, but I don't follow. I start my app, and I see it create a queue (I'm watching it  using the web based admin console on the rabbit server). I then cause a message to be sent, and there is no indication in my receiver app that a message has arrived. I send another, and it works as expected. I never stopped the app between sending the message and trying to receive it.

Comment: Also, It was my intention to have the queue disappear when the app is not running.  In fact I changed the app quite a bit since I posted that note to use the AnonymousQueue class instead, because I need multiple consumers to all receive the message. I got that working, but the same problem with missing the first message still happens. When I get back to work tomorrow I'll try your fix and look over my new code, and try to understand what you mean. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh!  I see what you mean about the boot jar versions thanks for pointing that out. I'll downgrade the starter tomorrow.

Comment: It really makes no sense. There must be something else going on. Thanks for posting your complete app. I pasted it into mine and that's when I noticed the auto delete queue. Can you post your publisher? Edit the question, don't try to add it in a comment. Also provide your exact test procedure/timing.

Comment: I'm happy to do that, anything that makes it easier for someone to help me :-) Tomorrow I'll add more info, either a report that it's fixed or more of the code, pom, whatever. The publisher is a much bigger app, I'll pull out the relevant portions. I believe it uses a RabbitTemplate and ConveryAndSend() call.  Thanks very much, I have only a few days to get this thing deployed and, as you can guess, I'm behind on this part.

Comment: Thanks. It's got to be something simple. This stuff just works. Just a heads up, though, from mid afternoon EDT tomorrow I will be traveling and will have limited time for the rest of the week.

Comment: I have updated the question with much more information, thanks again!

Comment: `>As far as the timing of this error, the publisher program is running before I start this listener. I start the listener... ` Do you wait until the listener is fully initialized - i.e. check on the rabbit console that the queue exists and is bound to the exchange. If you do, then I have no clue what's happening. The next thing I would try (on the producer side) is to set the mandatory bit and [configure the template and connection factory to handle returned messages](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/_reference.html#_publisher_returns).

Comment: BTW, with a fanout, a routing key is not needed `configSvc.getRabbitQueue()` in the template `send()` is meaningless, you can replace it with `""`.

Comment: Yes, after I start the listener I check the Rabbit console app and see the new queue with the random name. Then I fire off a message. I'll make the changes you suggest and report back. And thanks for mentioning about the queue for send(), I was wondering about that. Thank you again!

Comment: You can test the returns by sending a message while your consumer is down.

Comment: Issue resolved. In the producer, removing the routing key (queue name) from the second parameter of the rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend() call resolved it. I set it to "" as you suggested and the issue went away. Thank you very much, safe travels!